# Send mail in laravel 5x (xampp, php 7, windows, local)

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5

i'm doing sendmail using laravel , but error 
i'm try

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=abcd@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

but eror

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

Help me fix.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you're using the correct port number. "465" worked for me.

Also ensure you have correctly configured your gmail account as such.

Go to your Gmail account, perform following modification:

Go to Settings >  Protocols > SMTP and select "Delivery of Email" tab

Enter "smtp.gmail.com" in the Remote Host name field.

Enter "465" as the port number.

Check "Server requires authentication".

Enter your Google Mail address in the Username field.

Enter your Google Mail password in the password field.

Check mark "Use SSL"

Save all changes.

Comment: May be you should share the code that you're using for the sendmail